# How can I replace nan with 1 in a specific condition

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

In my program, I have some arrays and I am using a simple formula to calculate a value. The code I am using

```
from itertools import combinations
import numpy as np

res = [
    np.array([[12.99632095], [29.60571445], [-1.85595153], [68.78926787], [2.75185088], [2.75204384]]),
    np.array([[15.66458062], [0], [-3.75927882], [0], [2.30128711], [197.45459974]]),
    np.array([[10.66458062], [0], [0], [-2.65954113], [-2.30128711], [197.45459974]]),
]


def cal():
    pairs = combinations(res, 2)
    results = []
    for pair in pairs:
        r = np.concatenate(pair, axis=1)
        r1 = r[:, 0]
        r2 = r[:, 1]
        sign = np.sign(r1 * r2)
        result = np.multiply(sign, np.min(np.abs(r), axis=1) / np.max(np.abs(r), axis=1))

        results.append(result)
    return results
```

The output I am getting is

```
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
  result = np.multiply(sign, np.min(np.abs(r), axis=1) / np.max(np.abs(r), axis=1))
[array([0.82966287, 0.        , 0.49369882, 0.        , 0.83626883,
       0.0139376 ]), array([ 0.82058458,  0.        ,  0.        , -0.03866215, -0.83626883,
        0.0139376 ]), array([ 0.68080856,         nan,  0.        ,  0.        , -1.        ,
        1.        ])]
```

I here, I am getting `nan` for the 3rd output array. I understand, I got `nan` because of `0/0`.

As the size of the array or the position of `0` is not fixed. So, I want to change the code in this way, if I get `0/0`, here, instead of `nan` I want to save `1`.

Could you tell me how can I handle this `nan`?

Comment: numpy has a function especially designed for this use case: `np.nan_to_num()`

Comment: @obchardon thanks. Did you mean, to change the output array after getting `nan`? Actually, I wanted to save `1` is I get `0/0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of possible solutions:

```
import itertools as it

def cal():
    pairs = it.combinations(res, 2)
    rv = []
    for pair in pairs:
        r = np.concatenate(pair, axis=1)
        sign = np.sign(np.prod(r, axis=1))
        t1 = np.min(np.abs(r), axis=1)
        t2 = np.max(np.abs(r), axis=1)
        ratio = np.full(shape=r.shape[0], fill_value=1.)
        np.divide(t1, t2, out=ratio, where=np.not_equal(t2, 0.))
        wrk = np.full(shape=r.shape[0], fill_value=1.)
        np.multiply(sign, ratio, out=wrk, where=np.not_equal(t2, 0.))
        rv.append(wrk)
    return rv
```

Instead of `np.sign(r1 * r2)` I used `np.sign(np.prod(r, axis=1))`.

Then the trick to set default values instead of *NaN* is that I created
an array filled with this default value and called `np.divide` passing
*out* and *where* to divide only where the divisor is not *0*.

The last step is *np.multiply*, with just the same *where* condition.

To test this code and pretty print the result, you can run:

```
with np.printoptions(formatter={'float': '{: 9.5f}'.format}):
    result = cal()
    for tbl in result:
        print(tbl)
```

The result is:

```
[  0.82966   0.00000   0.49370   0.00000   0.83627   0.01394]
[  0.82058   0.00000   0.00000  -0.03866  -0.83627   0.01394]
[  0.68081   1.00000   0.00000   0.00000  -1.00000   1.00000]
```

As you can see, in the last case there are 2 *1.0* values, coresponding
with same values in the second and third source array.

Comment: Thank you very much. Just give me some time, after applying in my code, I will let you know.